# How do I hold SPI high value?

Tags: spi, wiringpi

I'm using wiringPi spi library to communicate two raspberries. As the spi clks aren't synchronised, I don't read the high values, since they are only a pulse. Is there a way to hold the high value during the whole clk?

Thanks in advance

Comment: please draw a SPI communication timing diagram that shows what you are trying to do

Comment: Ah, Clk is only tne tick, tick, tick signal. It is only the first MISO that sync things. But CE can also syn things. I have not thought about that before. Perhaps I should look at signal and data wave forms and think a bit.  https://imgur.com/gallery/aFVfLg2

Comment: Let me do some brainstorming. One possible solution is NOT to use the Rpi's built in CEx of SPIy buses. Instead, disconnect them, and use your own CEz, say ONE Rpi or MCP23017 GPIO pin to chip select/enable the hardware devices connected to some or all of SPI 0~5 buses.